# Jquery Hover function not changing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a grid of pixels and want it to change to black when hovered.
The problem is that the event is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function makeGrid(k) {
    var size = 320 / k;
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      $(".container").append("<div class=row></div>");
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
      $(".row").append("<div class=square></div>");
    }
    $('.square').css({
      'height': size,
      'width': size
    });
  }


  $('.square').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass(".hover");
  })

  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
    $(".container").empty();
    makeGrid(16);

  })

  $('.start').on('click', function() {
    var n = prompt("Set the size");
    $(".container").empty();
    makeGrid(n);
  })
})
```

```css
.square {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
}

.hover {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 50%;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="clear">New Grid</button>
  <button class="start">Start</button>
  <button class="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you dynamically add your divs, you can't use `.hover()` and have to use `.on()` with `mouseenter` instead. Also when using `.addClass()` you just use the class' name with no period being prefixed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function makeGrid(k) {
    var size = 320 / k;
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      $(".container").append("<div class=row></div>");
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
      $(".row").append("<div class=square></div>");
    }
    $('.square').css({
      'height': size,
      'width': size
    });
  }
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".square", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  });
  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
    $(".container").empty();
    makeGrid(16);
  })
  $('.start').on('click', function() {
    var n = prompt("Set the size");
    $(".container").empty();
    makeGrid(n);
  })
})
```

```css
.square {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
}

.hover {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 50%;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="clear">New Grid</button>
  <button class="start">Start</button>
  <button class="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```